# Add template in Twig-Excel bundle

Tags: excel, symfony, twig

Some have some example of using template in twig-excel bundle.

Here I give you an example of how I have used it but I can't make it work.

```
    {% xlsdocument {'template': './template_advanced.xlsx'} %}
      {% xlssheet %}
        {% xlsrow %}
            {% xlscell %}Hello2{% endxlscell %}
        {% endxlsrow %}
        {% xlsrow %}
            {% xlscell 1 %}Bar2{% endxlscell %}
        {% endxlsrow %}
      {% endxlssheet %}
    {% endxlsdocument %}
```

I have changed the address of the file but it don't load.
If I skip the code `{'template': '@./template_advanced.xlsx'}`, the excel is generated.

Thanks!

Comment: So ... what exactly doesn’t work? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I am trying to generate excel. Excel it not generated when I add the template.